# Two way selector in android for start and end point

Tags: android

I am making a video editor and I want to make a bar with two sliders (for start and end point) just like the following image [image]

Do android provide some native view for this? Or any ideas? :)

Comment: NO, You can do it via progressBar

Comment: @MdAbdulGafur How? :)

Comment: @berserk  means your start and end point also slides and your middle point also slides ?

Comment: Check following link. This may help you ... https://code.google.com/p/range-seek-bar/

Comment: @RahulGupta Sorry for the confusion, I don't need middle point.. I just want a bar to select start and end points, thats it.. I am not playing the video

Comment: @berserk have you design seek bar for it  or just coding is done?

Comment: @RahulGupta Its just a snapshot I took from google images. Design is not the thing. I want this same functionality :)